# Analyzing a coredump wth GDB from a different system gives .dynamic section warnings

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, embedded, coredump

I have a program built on a Host machine with an SDK for a specific target Machine. The program is then ran on the target machine and crashes. When I try to analyze it on the Host machine I receive several errors in the this:

```
warning: .dynamic section for 
"/opt/rcsos-2.1.0/x86_3.12.15-rt25-r1/sysroots/x86-rcs-linux/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0"
is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
```

I have the sysroot to the root in the SDK, and it seems like it is trying to use the shared library in said SDK and the correct debug information file is present in the .debug subdirectory of the directory that the library resides in, I'm not sure what is missing and causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason you might see this error is different versions of shared objects on the host and target. Output of the `file` command invoked on a shared object includes the build ID; if the build ID disagrees between host and target, that would be consistent with other errors, like the one in the message you asked about.

Comment: Turns out it was a build-id mismatch.